# Redis command in NodeJS hangs indefinitely

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-elasticache

I’m trying to insert some data into a redis cache  using the Redis NPM library but even tho’ it says it’s connected, every single command after connects hangs indefinitely and I don’t understand what is the problem since there is no errors being printed in the console.

```
// Connect to Redis Elasticache
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
        host: configuration.REDIS_HOST,
        port: configuration.REDIS_PORT,
    },
});
redisClient.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected!'); //Gets Printed
});

redisClient.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
});
redisClient.on("ready", (err) => {
    console.log("ready"); //Gets Printed
});

await redisClient.connect();
console.log(redisClient.isOpen); //returns true

await redisClient.RPUSH(“data”, “some data”);

console.log("Pushed Message"); // never executes
```

Have tried multiple commands such as get,set and none of them works, all of them hangs.

Comment: Do you have [`TLS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html) enabled on the server side?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman
 Yes, i do have it enabled

Comment: Are you trying to connect using `stunnel` (if so, try to connect using `redis-cli` first please)? or directly (if so, you'll need to pass some more options to `createClient`, see [this file](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md#tls))?

BTW, you don't get any `error` events?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman thanks for your reply. That’s what exactly I was missing. I was using TLS but didn’t have the TLS option set as true in createClient. Adding that solved it. Thanks!